# Debugging a C++ source code that has a GUI front end using Netbeans in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, user-interface, netbeans

I have a C++ open source code comprising of thousands of lines of code in a number of files that help run a robotic hand grasping simulator tool. It has a front end GUI with option to import a variety of robotic hands and objects and grasping actions performed on them. Although I have understood some of the concepts being used, and understood some source files by skimming through, but I am unable to get a gist of how the process works as a whole. I want to figure out that by pressing a specific gui button, which files and functions are being called. Is there a way to start debugging the software gui code from start?

I have knowledge of write technique and step debugging technique for small codes that I write by myself, but doing so for a code that have hundreds of files with hundereds of objects is way too confusing.

Also, the debugging menu has two options that I can use, 1-Debug Project: While doing so, the user interface window opens bypassing the breakpoints that I have placed. 2- step into: It always starts in Disassembly (main) and the step over,out are not grayed anymore and I can use them. Is that the assembly language of the code? Is there a simpler way to debug it?

Any kind of guidance and help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Listed below is the main file of the open source code, cant post a snapshot with breakpoints because of lesser reputation, mentioning them in comments.

```
/*! \file
\brief Program execution starts here.  Server is started, main window is built, 
and the interactive loop is started.

The main call returns an exit code as indicated by the graspit GUI (0 by default)
to provide feedback to calling program, if desired.
 */

#define GRASPITDBG

#include <iostream>
#include <graspitApp.h>
#include "graspitGUI.h"
#include "graspitServer.h"
#include "mainWindow.h"

#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincon.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
#ifdef GRASPITDBG
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("conin$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("conout$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);
    //ios::sync_with_stdio();
#endif
#endif
    //*******placed breakpoint1
    GraspItApp app(argc, argv); //shows the GraspIt! logo splash screen in the 
                                //center of  the screen.

    if (app.splashEnabled()) {
        app.showSplash();
        QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::waitCursor);
    }

    //******* placed breakpoint2

    GraspItGUI gui(argc, argv); // Implements the graspit user interface.
                                // Responsible for    creating both MainWindow and IVmgr.

    //This is the GraspIt TCP server. It can be used to connect to GraspIt from
    //external programs, such as Matlab.
    //On some machines, the Q3Socket segfaults at exit, so this is commented out by
    //default
    //GraspItServer server(4765);

    app.setMainWidget(gui.getMainWindow()->mWindow);
    QObject::connect(qApp, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

    if (app.splashEnabled()) {
        app.closeSplash();
        QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
    }

    if (!gui.terminalFailure()) {
        gui.startMainLoop();
    }
    return gui.getExitCode();
}
```

Comment: Put breakpoints in your code, run project from netbeans in debug mode and check when breakpoints are hit. What's the difference with your small code?

Comment: I am running in debug mode but I am unsure where to put breakpoints. The main file only contains a class object for splash screen and another for GUI creation plus some more line of code for external integration with softwares like MATLAB. I have randomly placed breakpoints in the GUI file but when I stat debugging by pressing "Step into" the simulator GUI appears and I don't see the debugger stopping at any breakpoints.

Comment: You must understand program workflow. To check of buttons work, you must study the code and find, for a button, which slot(s) is(are) called.

Comment: Actually I was trying to understand the workflow through debugging but by running the project in debugging mode, the GUI window appears bypassing all the breakpoints that I had placed before it even created the main window.

Comment: Use the `gdb` debugger on the command line.

Comment: I have started using gdb in the command line for the executable file but no debugging symbols were found. So to incorporate symbolic debugging information , -g was used to compile the source file. And I get to see a fatal error telling me a header file graspitApp.h wasn't found(Its's not in the same directory as the source file) . On the contrary, the project compiles in Netbeans without such errors.

Answer (score 0):

GUI buttons are usually associated with callback functions.
I would find out which function is associated with the button-of-interest and set a breakpoint there and start debugging.

[EDIT added after Reviewing your code]

If the breakpoints indicated in your code are not working, then the NetBeans project might have been corrupted somehow.
[An example, FYI](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233683)

I once had the same problem but with different reason (NetBeans + CMAKE setting mismatch).

If the breakpoints are working then..

Let's see `GraspItGUI`, for example, if you have set a breakpoint at the line 86 of `GraspItGUI.cpp` (if the version is the same as this [link](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/graspit/html/graspitGUI_8cpp_source.html)) which happens to be the first `if`-statement of `GraspItGUI::GraspItGUI`, the program should stop at this point.

Comment: I am making use of breakpoints to understand the work flow. I have placed a few breakpoints where a small splash screen displays before the GUI appears. I have even placed a breakpoint before the GUI class object that implements the interface and is responsible for creating a main window. The project is cleaned and built successfully but when I start debugging, the GUI windows somehow appears without the debugger stopping at my assigned breakpoints. Can't understand why.

Comment: I' just hitting bushes here.. Is the program multithreaded? Does it have only one main executable? Is any of the breakpoints working? Maybe you can show initial part of the main program where it starts and where you have put breakpoints.

Comment: Can't tell if it's multi-threaded because I have worked with sequential programs so far. Yes, it has one executable main in the bin directory. I'll try to paste the main code where it starts along the breakpoints that the debugger ignores.

Comment: I am not sure but there might be some multi threading..Doing gdb (executable file) in cli and then starting the debugger shows : [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Comment: I have edited my answer to respond to you.  Do breakpoints 1 and 2 work? and GraspIt source code is part of this project?

Comment: Thank you for taking out your time to help Keugyeol, but the breakpoints are not being triggered. Like you suggested (in your edited answer) the debugger does not stop at line 86, the if-statement.

Comment: I found the other link you posted titled "An example FYI" quite interesting. I have the same version of Netbeans (7.3.1) not upgraded from any older version though. Particularly tried to follow comment 8  by Blackbird which he does for Netbeans Run mode. I gave similar path to the Debug option. But that doesn't work either. The executable runs without stopping at breakpoints.